# Need some help for Japanese font identifying

Tags: font-identification, japanese

It's a 2014 TV drama title. I've searched this for a long time but got nothing, since online font identification websites usually cannot recognize Japanese words. So if anyone knows the detail about this font, please let me know and I'd really appreciate your help!

[image]

Comment: We've had a lot of questions on Japanese fonts recently. Unfortunately, it's normally the same answer: nobody here seems to know much about them and these questions rarely get good answers. Maybe try a Japanese graphic design forum? But this could easily be hand-drawn, important graphics like titles often are.

Comment: There is a website which can find Japanese fonts from an image, semi-automatically: https://en.likefont.com/  You have to manually type in the characters though, so it's not much use for people who can't read or type in Japanese. You may also have to edit the image to get a good result - for example, not sure how well it will work with those textured characters, or characters that have little spacing between them.

Comment: Also note (this goes for all languages) - graphic designers don't always use actual fonts. Sometimes letters/characters are hand written/drawn from scratch. Sometimes designers may even alter letter/character outlines from a standard font, to customize them.  Letters/characters are not always an actual font you can download.